# How do I constantly get the value of a Tkinter entry box without a button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to be able to get the value of an entry box in tkinter repeatedly without a button. For example, if a type '0987654321' in the entry box another variable can be saved of these values constantly being updated by whatever is being typed in that entry box.

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea - you're going to receive all sorts of meaningless values, while the user is in the middle of typing in a multi-digit number.  But if you must do this, one way would be to write a function that calls `.get()` on the Entry and does whatever you want with the value - you call this function once, it schedules another call to itself (maybe 100-500 milliseconds later) via `.after()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for (See sample code below).

What we are doing here is tracing the value of the entry widget and if changes are made, it is calling the function to replace that label with the new value. **Be sure to check the comments within my code** - It breaks it down better.

---

If my example doesn't make sense, here is a link to another.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks

Here are some better examplanations of ***args** and ***kwargs**

https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

```
#Entry StringVar
year_var = tk.StringVar()
#Entry box and placement
tk.Entry(root, text=(year_var), justify="center").place(x=150, y=250, width="100", anchor="center")

#Fucntion that will be called when entry is changed
def function_called(*args):
    tk.Label(root, text=year_var.get(), justify="center").place(x=150, y=320, width="100", anchor="center")

#Tracing the entry and calling the above function 
year_var.trace("w", function_called)
```